# Result of Color.GetPixel().equals(Color.Blue) comes out false

Tags: c#, colors, getpixel

```
Color c1 = image.GetPixel (7, 400);
Color c2 = Color.Blue;
Console.WriteLine (image.GetPixel (7, 400));
Console.WriteLine (Color.Blue);
Console.WriteLine (c1.Equals(c2));
```

Console output:

```
Color [A=255, R=0, G=0, B=255]
Color [Blue]
False
```

I'm new to C# and I have NO idea why this is returning false. Can anyone please give me some insight as to why this doesn't work?

I'm trying to use it in this context.

```
for (int i = 0; i < image.Height; i++)  //loop through rows
            {
            for (int j = 0; j < image.Width; j++) //loop through columns
            {
                //Console.WriteLine ("i = " + i);
                //Console.WriteLine ("j = " + j);
                if ((image.GetPixel (i, j)) == Color.Blue) 
                {
                    return new Tuple<int, int>(i,j);
                }

                if (i == image.Height-1 && j == image.Width-1) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Image provided does not have a starting point. \n" +
                                                 "Starting points should be marked by Blue.");
                    Environment.Exit (0);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: So it turns out if i make both values into Argb, then it comes out a true but is there a way to do this without doing so?

Comment: I think you need to do Color c1 = Color.FromARGB(image.GetPixel (7, 400));

Comment: Says it cannot convert Color to Int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already noted, the following example will return false:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1);
bmp.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.Blue);
Color c1 = bmp.GetPixel(0, 0);
Console.WriteLine("GetPixel:" + c1);
Console.WriteLine("Color:" + Color.Blue);
Console.WriteLine("Equal?:" + c1.Equals(Color.Blue));

Console.ReadLine();
```

The reason is a little tricky to understand:

If you look at the source code of the Bitmap-Class, you will find

```
public Color GetPixel(int x, int y) { 
   //lot of other code     
   return Color.FromArgb(color); 
 }
```

http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/CommonUI/System/Drawing/Bitmap@cs/1/Bitmap@cs

And the documentation for `Color.Equals()` says:

> To compare colors based solely on their ARGB values, you should use
>   the ToArgb method. This is because the Equals and Equality members
>   determine equivalency using more than just the ARGB value of the
>   colors. For example, Black and FromArgb(0,0,0) are not considered
>   equal, since Black is a named color and FromArgb(0,0,0) is not.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e03x8ct2(v=vs.110).aspx

so, the returned Color is not equal to `Color.Blue` - even if it is `Color.Blue` in terms of ARGB values.

To bypass this, use:

```
Console.WriteLine("Equal?:" + c1.ToArgb().Equals(Color.Blue.ToArgb()));
```

As last line of the example.

Comment: Yeah this is what i ended up doing. Thanks very much!